# Same as everyone else...Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot past login/password

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, login

OK...
I was prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 on my Asus Eee PC.
Something 'minimal' loads, THEN, goes to another black screen asking for 
LOGIN: and PASSWORD.

I Log In successfully.

THEN, the following appears: Last Login: Aug. 2 06:18:12 EDT 2016 tty1
b****@b****-1005HA:~$

and that's it???

I guess I'm going to lose all of my previous software, pics and documents!

Are there any "Commands" that I can use to return back to the previous version of 14.04?
or
Should I just forget Ubuntu and install Debian?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but you could try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop package with aptitude. I think you need a Ethernet connection and if the Eee doesn't have an Ethernet port as I expect then you could find a USB Ethernet adapter. But before this you could use the recovery from Grub menu by hitting ESC while loading Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**For HOME directories with no encryption**

> Note: I have done the nasty solution and the epiphany, the others are
>   in theory for me. The workaround to the internet connection I have
>   done many times. You can reinstall a whole system even when the home folder is within the root folder if the software can match in version, in the case of an upgrade all software is up to date so you can simply re-install with latest updates.If you don't have internet connection you can try the work around. Links have nothing to do with the solutions I just wanted the *Orange* coloring.

- **Nasty steps**

Boot a 16.04 Ubuntu live session and check if the **software sources** was correctly changed if yes then configuration files should be in order so you can delete everything but **HOME** where your *user* files are. Check the option to install updates while installing and you should be back in the game. And don't forget **not to format** (**[Don't format the disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3_2entulkw)**) the disk during installation, I think you'll get a *non-sense* **warning** since you already deleted any system binaries ( *Let's consider that a Bee boop* ).

- **Nice Steps**

If software sources was not installed correctly then you'll need to run the `apt-get dist-upgrade` command from the terminal you have logged on.

If yes then install aptitude and reinstall the ubuntu-desktop package.

- **Workaround the lack of internet connection**

Download the software packages from another computer and copy via USB flash card to the path `/var/cache/apt/archives`

You can also check this folder in your installation to see if the update packages are still there just waiting for **autoremove** help them meet their fate.

- **The epiphany solution** ( you computer will realize why deja-dup sounds like deja vu )

> This one works with encryption if your are logged in

In your tty console do :

```
cd /
```

Insert an external disk

`lsblk` to see the path to the disk

---

This is my output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 215.6G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 465.8G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   1   3.7G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   1.5G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   1  29.1G  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   1  29.1G  0 part /media/user/DOC
```

My USB, AKA ( Uniform Speedy Bunker )

**└─sdd1   8:49   1  29.1G  0 part /media/user/DOC**

---

**So now inside the root "/"** ( you can run "pwd" to Print Working Directory ) :

```
cp -rva home /media/user/DOC/home_bkp
```

[This will copy every file, hidden ones included.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSHnQux4PjE)

Install a clean system with identical settings and copy the files from **home_bkp** to your **HOME** folder.

> Note :  Users are identified with ID's by Linux, usually a single user
>   system will have an ID 1000 AFAIK